# Array print in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

1:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
```

2:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;++i){
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";
```

I am trying to print my array using these two statements. But, both of them are giving different outputs. why is it so?

Comment: i++ first assigns the value and then increments , ++i first increments and then assigns it

Comment: code is self explainatory one of them is starting from 0th index and another from 1st index

Comment: It's very likely that the second loop will go out of bounds, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also, if you knew the contents of the array `a`, then the output provided should have been a very big hint about what's happening, as the second loop would start printing the second element.

Answer (score 3):

The first loop runs over indexes [0, n-1]. The second loop runs over indexes [1, n]. Since these are different indexes, you're getting different results.

Answer (score 2):

lets say your array is this `int a[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};`

The reason you are getting different answers is because the index that array starts from are counted from 0, this means if you have an array of size 8 it will start the count index like this 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 not like this 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.

If you try to `cout<<a[5];` you will get the value `6` printed and not the value `5` (with respect to above array example).

So based on your first for loop, the loop is starting the index from 0 (which it should be if you want to print all the elements of array)

Where as the second for loop is starting from index 1 (which means you are skipping the index 0 where value 1 is stored)

Hence different outputs.